# Missing package Microsoft.NETCore.App.Host.arch-x64 dotnet restore error

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, archlinux

I am trying to work with NET at ArchLinux. As per the instructions provided [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Visual_Studio_Code), I am trying to install netcoredbg. The thing is, when installing with *mkpkg*, I get the following error:

```
-- Compiler type CLANG: /usr/bin/clang++
-- Configuring done (1.4s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/Weinman/Downloads/netcoredbg/src/netcoredbg-2.2.3-992/build
[  5%] Built target linenoise
[  7%] Built target example
[ 21%] Built target corguids
[ 21%] Built target buildinfo
[ 22%] Compiling generrmsg/bin/generrmsg.dll
MSBuild version 17.4.8+6918b863a for .NET
  Determining projects to restore...
/home/Weinman/Downloads/netcoredbg/src/netcoredbg-2.2.3-992/build/src/generrmsg/generrmsg.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package Microsoft.NETCore.App.Host.arch-x64. No packages exist with this id in source(s): nuget.org                   
  Failed to restore /home/Weinman/Downloads/netcoredbg/src/netcoredbg-2.2.3-992/build/src/generrmsg/generrmsg.csproj (in 1,41 sec).

ERROR al compilar.
```

I did some homework and I do know that Microsoft.NETCore.App.Host.linux-x64 exists.

Where should I be able to change whatever config needed for changing the package dotnet is trying to install with the real thing instead of Microsoft.NETCore.App.Host.arch-x64?

I also tried installing NuGet and adding to netcoredbg/src/netcoredbg-2.2.3-992/build/src/generrmsg csproj the Microsoft.NETCore.App.Host.linux-x64 with *dotnet add package* command, which was actually useless.

Whenever I use dotnet restore, this mistake happens, so I guessed I need to modify dotnet configuration in my OS for making sure dotnet restore requests packages which actually exist, but I am totally lost here.

Answer (score 0):

I have found something which helps me temporally [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=265923), but I would be more comfortable if I had this as a global default setting instead of changing every .csproj everywhere.

Comment: It is possible setting an env variable DOTNET_RUNTIME_ID in which the RID is overriden and thus, this error is corrected